# Pinta crashes on load in Windows 7 x64 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, crash, pinta

Unfortunately I can't really give much more information unless anybody can suggest where I should look for logs or dumps etc?

Simply put, when I load the program I immediately get the error "Pinta Has Stopped Working".

I have tried:

- Running as administrator
- Installing to different partitions
- Installing to folders with no spaces in directory structure

I have installed the GTK# for .Net 2.12.9 as required in order to install Pinta.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I just installed Pinta on Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium, and it works just fine. I can suggest running something like SysInternals Process Monitor against Pinta to see what it is looking for before it crashes. Other than that, I would suggest a repair install on Gtk#, maybe turning off UAC to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be replicated also on Windows 7 32 bit. I think this is a problem in the registration of environment variables for Gtk# -- the installer registers a variable called GTK_BASEPATH (that I think it is used by Gtk# to find dependent libraries) but this is not propagated to Windows correctly (if you call `set` from `cmd.exe` you will not see this variable), thus causing the error you saw.

If you reboot your computer after installation of GTK#, Pinta will start without any problems. Hope this helps.